# React / Why the props are not in the parent tag?

Tags: reactjs

Hello

I am trying to understand how React passes props informations from parent to child.

In this [example](https://codepen.io/moiamy/pen/WNzqrEE) the App function returns :

```js
 return (
    <div className="app">
      <Grid>
        <Palettes palettes={palettes} />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And in the Grid function, it passes the props property.

```js
const Grid = (props) => {
  return <div className="grid" {...props} />;
};
```

But I don't get why the App doesn't provides `palettes={palettes}` to the grid tab instead, as it is the parent, like :

```js
return (
    <div className="app">
      <Grid palettes={palettes} >
        <Palettes />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Which of course doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [blog](https://codeburst.io/a-complete-guide-to-props-children-in-react-c315fab74e7c)

Here we are passing Palettes Component as a Child component.
This means that Grid component is a parent component.

Any data passed in between the `<Grid>{ /* data */ }</Grid>` component is sent as a prop to the child component. We can look at this by doing a `console.log(props)` in the grid component.

[image]

Therefore the props can be accessed in the grid component.

Answer (score 0):

`<Grid>` has no props, and children are translated to `children` prop, so it cannot be expected that Grid props contain `palette`. `{...props}` results in Grid being rendered as:

```
<div className="grid">
  <Palettes palettes={palettes} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example that doesnt work is setting `props.palettes` to the `Grid` component, which does nothing with it but `palettes` are expected in exact `Palettes` component. And they are not passed in your not working example.

`Grid` component can be represented in multiple ways, they are all equivalent, maybe that will help you to understand better what is happening.

Added `someOtherProp` for example purposes

```
<div className="app">
  <Grid someOtherProp="123">
    <Palettes palettes={palettes} />
  </Grid>
</div>
```

And 3 equivalents of `Grid` component:

```
const Grid = (props) => {
  return <div className="grid" {...props} />;
};

const Grid = ({ children, ...restProps }) => {
  console.log(children.type, children.props);
  // ƒ Palettes() {}, {palettes: Array(18)}

  console.log(restProps);
  // {someOtherProp: "123"}
  return <div className="grid" children={children} {...restProps} />;
};

const Grid = ({ children, ...restProps }) => {
  return (
    <div className="grid" {...restProps}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see, `Grid` component has its own `props`, and the `children` component also has its own props. So if you move `<Grid palettes={palettes}>` you just move palletes to `Grid` in same way as `someOtherProp` and `Grid` has nothig to do with them. But `<Palettes>` will miss them now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it is the **Palettes component** that takes care of **displaying each color palette**.

The **Grid component** is **just there to display the palettes** in a certain way

Also , what I notice is that the props in the Grid component are useless in my opinion